# How To Pass Tcpclient Between 2 Forms C#

Tags: c#, wpf

This Is the first form:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    TcpClient client = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Connect()
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8826);

        CreateRoomWindow menuWindow = new CreateRoomWindow(client);
        menuWindow.Show();

        this.Close();
    } 
}
```

This is the second form:

```
public partial class CreateRoomWindow : Window
{
    TcpClient client;
    const int createRoomMessage = 206;

    public CreateRoomWindow(TcpClient loggedClient)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client = loggedClient;
    }
}
```

I tried to pass the TcpClient to the another window
But when I click on the createTheRoom Button its happen:

```
private void CreateTheRoom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string message = "2060068{\"answerTimeout\":2,\"maxUsers\":22,\"questionCount\":2,\"roomName\":\"Name\"}";

    int timedSize = message.Length;
    string size = timedSize.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');

    message = Convert.ToString(createRoomMessage) + size + message;

    Byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
 }
```

The program down with the exception System.InvalidOperationException
in the last line

So my question is How can I pass the TcpClient To make it work

Comment: What if you don't open the `CreateRoomWindow` and do `NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();` in `Connect` method of  `MainWindow` itself? Do you get the same error ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya If I do this in the MainWindow itself its works

Comment: Looks like the connection is closed by the time `CreateRoomWindow` is opened and button is clicked. You should to `client.Connect()` in ButtonClick before you do `client.GetStream();`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I tried to do client.Connect() in the CreateRoomWindow but I get the exception "A connect request was made on an already connected socket"

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

`Show` displays the form and returns control to the caller, so in this code, `Close()` gets called almost immediately:

```
CreateRoomWindow menuWindow = new CreateRoomWindow(client);
menuWindow.Show();
this.Close();  //Executes immediately
```

This is a problem, because there is only one instance you're working with, and if you close it in one place, it's closed to everyone.

### Solution #1. Make the child form modal.

You can delay the call until after the form is closed by using ShowDialog instead:

```
CreateRoomWindow menuWindow = new CreateRoomWindow(client);
menuWindow.ShowDialog();
this.Close();  //Executes after form is closed
```

### Solution #2. Close it when the child form is closed.

Another option is to close it in the "FormClosed" handler for the child form:

```
CreateRoomWindow menuWindow = new CreateRoomWindow(client);
menuWindow.ShowDialog();
//Doesn't call close any more

public partial class CreateRoomWindow : Window
{
    TcpClient client;
    const int createRoomMessage = 206;

    public CreateRoomWindow(TcpClient loggedClient)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client = loggedClient;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        client.Close();  //Closes after we're done with the form
    }
}
```

Note: You must register the Form1_FormClosed handler, which you would typically do by double-clicking the event in the property sheet it in the form designer window in Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried the solution 1 with the command showDialog But its still down in the NetworkStream stream Line

Comment: Is the client being closed somewhere else? Could it be timing out? Are you sure it connected successfully to begin with? You may have to step debug through the code and inspect the variables to see what is happening.